# The closed set in the product topology

Tags: general-topology

We know that for the product topology $X\times Y$, the open sets are generated by $U\times V$,where $U,V$ are open in $X,Y$ respectively. I am considering the closed sets in $X\times Y$, are they generated by the closed sets in $X$ and $Y$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If $A$ is closed in $X$ and $B$ is closed in $Y$, then $A=X\setminus A'$ and $B=Y\setminus B'$ for open sets $A'$ and $B'$.  But
$$A \times B = (X\setminus A') \times (Y\setminus B') = (X \times Y) \setminus ((A' \times Y) \cup (X \times B')),$$
so $A \times B$ is the complement of the open set $(A' \times Y) \cup (X \times B')$ in $X \times Y$ and thus closed.  This proves that the product of two closed sets is a closed set in the product topology.

But that doesn't mean that the products of closed sets form a basis for the closed sets in the product topology (as the products of the open sets form a basis for the open sets).  Consider the [cofinite topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology) on $X=Y=\mathbb N$.  Then $(\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\})\times(\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\})$ is open in the product topology, so its complement $D=(\mathbb{N}\times\{1\})\cup(\{1\}\times\mathbb{N})$ is closed.  But $D$ can't be expressed as the intersection of products of closed sets as the closed sets are either $\mathbb{N}$ or finite.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very old question but I want to make a comment here which I personally found helpful. Frunobulax's answer indeed shows that the products of closed sets do not form a basis for the product topology. However, the question as asked was whether they *generate* the product topology, and the answer to that question is yes (at least in the case of a finite product).

Let $C$ be a closed set in $Z := X \times Y$. Then $Z \setminus V$ is open we can write
$$X \setminus C = \bigcup_i U_i \times V_i $$
where $U_i$ is open in $X$ and $V_i$ is open in $Y$. We then have

$$C = Z\setminus \bigcup_i U_i \times V_i  = \bigcap_i Z\setminus( U_i \times V_i) $$
which by some basic set theory equals
$$\bigcap_i \bigg(\big((X\setminus U_i) \times V_i\big) \cup \big(U_i \times (Y\setminus V_i)\big) \cup \big((X\setminus U_i) \times (Y\setminus V_i)\big) \bigg)$$

But $X\setminus U_i$, $Y\setminus V_i$ are closed sets, so indeed every closed set in $X \times Y$ is an arbitrary intersection of a finite union of products of closed sets.